# how to change file content in text file

Tags: linux, bash

this is test.txt

```
hello mate
good morning
no worries
```

and this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

while
do
printf "whice one do you change? "
read change
printf "how to change? "
read after
done < test.txt
```

I want to change "good" to "gooood" in test.txt file

```
and here is conditions
-not using sed
-not using perl
```

How can I change it?
please give me a hand~!!!

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is the best tool for this simple replacement but if not allowed to use tools, you can revert back to bash functionality

```
 while read line; do echo ${line/good/goood}; done < good.txt > goood.txt
```

assuming the original file is good.txt, this will replace the string "good" to "goood" and write to goood.txt.

Comment: Nice touch. Enlightened by the small tweak of the echo command.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ sub(/good/, "goood"); print }' test.txt > tempfile && mv tempfile test.txt
```

or you could use awk with the in-place modifications :

```
awk -i inplace '{ sub(/good/, "goood"); print }' test.txt
```